# Ubuntu 16.04 First Time Install

Tags: boot, 16.04

I'm creating a second PC to do some tinkering with out of parts from my old PC. I install Ubuntu just fine and it tells me to remove the media and press ENTER.

After I do, it boots to a "Loading Operating System" and stays there. After some tinkering I was able to add a boot flag to sda2 that I read about somewhere. But now it just stays at a flashing underscore cursor. There is some text that flashes too quick for me to see right before that.

I've tried going through and adding acpi=off to the Grub file through Boot-Repair. The only way I was able to actually get to the Ubuntu desktop was by using the option to "Try Ubuntu before install". I've fresh formatted and wiped the entire drive and it still won't boot to anything.

I've checked around the BIOS, I have no "Secure Boot" or ACPI options besides something that sets it to SR1 or SR3?

Here's a pastebin of my latest log from Boot-Repair: http://paste2.org/wXhOeM7H

My motherboard is: GA-Z68A-D3H-B3

Thank you for any answers!

Edit: The text that flashes on the screen for a moment after I think it's loading is saying a bunch of:
"Failed to start... (can't read the filename)"
"Failed to start... (can't read the filename)"
"Failed to start... (can't read the filename)"
"Failed to start... (can't read the filename)"

Comment: It is important to get what filename the 'Failed to start' says. Try video-recording the boot and looking at the video frame-by-frame.

Comment: It's an 'old PC': Does it have an UEFI BIOS? Your setup appears to require one, there is no MBR boot, so if it needs a legacy boot.... it won't...

Comment: To be more specific I bought these parts 6 years ago.

I posted the motherboard (GA-Z68A-D3H-B3) which has an Intel Core i5-2500K CPU, 8GB RAM Corsair Vengeance, 1x M4 Corsair 128GB SSD, 2x Western Digital Red 4TB, Asus DVD/CD Drive.

The BIOS appeared to be "Award 1999-2007" or something like that.

Comment: Should I update my BIOS to a newer version to unlock more menu options to switch to a format that works?

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3856#sp

2 x 32 Mbit flash
Use of licensed AWARD BIOS
Support for DualBIOS™
PnP 1.0a, DMI 2.0, SM BIOS 2.4, ACPI 1.0b

Found this on the bottom of the page too:
Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors, please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website.


There appears to be the option of: 
U1D(UEFI BIOS) 2.95 MB 2013/03/06
on the download BIOS page. I will try flashing to that after work unless someone points out otherwise.

Comment: When installing Ubuntu to a UEFI system i found that I had to press `f12` to take me to a 'one-time boot menu' and select my USB stick from the UEFI Boot options in order to load the installation media in 'UEFI mode'. If it's installing in 'Legacy mode' & your system doesn't have the legacy 'MBR boot' as Mark Williams suggested, then check that you're booting the installation media in UEFI mode.

Comment: So instead of using the DVD I burned the .iso to I should try installing from USB stick and selecting it as the boot option via F12?

Comment: Check that `f12` takes you to a one-time boot menu (different BIOS may require different f key to take you to a 'one-time boot menu' but I'm assuming `f12` is fairly standard) and the DVD may show up in the UEFI Boot options in the same way that the USB does for me.

Comment: Yeah, I know F12 brings up my boot selection menu. But doing it from this menu is different than just letting the disc run on boot and installing from there? I'll look around when I get home from work and try this as well.

Comment: Yup, when I inserted my installation medium and booted my machine, it loaded the Ubuntu installer and went about installing it in Legacy mode. In order to get it to specifically load the installation medium in UEFI mode (and subsequently install it with a UEFI bootloader) I had to select that option from the one-time boot menu. It's likely that your machine will behave in a similar fashion. The option should be there for a DVD, but if not, try it using a USB as your installation medium.

Comment: Weird! Thanks for the info pHeLiOn, and Mark Williams, I'll try some of those options tonight and make a comment with results!

Comment: Tried both CD Drive options through F12 and both had the same result, no boot loader is being installed. Currently using "Rufus" to create a USB bootable Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Flash drive worked perfectly. I didn't change any .iso or anything, same steps. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu to a UEFI system i found that I had to press f12 to take me to a 'one-time boot menu' and select my USB stick from the UEFI Boot options in order to load the installation media in 'UEFI mode'. If it's installing in 'Legacy mode' & your system doesn't have the legacy 'MBR boot' as Mark Williams suggested, then check that you're booting the installation media in UEFI mode.

From pHeLiOn and Mark Williams